# Max text Repl Size equivalent quey in Azure Sql Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-managed-instance

We are trying to execute the below statement in Azure SQL Database. Is there any workaround this or equivalent query for Azure SQL Database.

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
EXEC sp_configure 'max text repl size (B)', -1
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options',0
RECONFIGURE WITH OVERRIDE
```

can this bet set or changed from Azure portal?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: No, you can't configure the max text repl size Server Configuration using Azure portal because these settings can only be set by the user who has required permission. Therefore, user with permission can only configure using T-SQL commands.

Refer: [Configure the max text repl size Server Configuration Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-text-repl-size-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16#Restrictions)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was some of the data was getting truncated when we enabled cdc on the azure sql database. We wanted to execute above tsql statement to alter the replication size but we couldn't because of restrictions on product side. We implemented change tracking in order to get around the problem

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).